# JBoss won't deploy my WAR file

Tags: jboss

This is the log which I get when I deploy the file. However after the last line the log gets stucks. I don't know why it happens.

```
14:08:03,556 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/web-console, warUrl=.../deploy/management/console-mgr.sar/web-console.war/ 
14:08:04,320 INFO  [MailService] Mail Service bound to java:/Mail 
14:08:04,741 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-ha-local-jdbc.rar 
14:08:04,897 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-ha-xa-jdbc.rar 
14:08:05,022 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-local-jdbc.rar 
14:08:05,178 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jboss-xa-jdbc.rar 
14:08:05,584 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/jms/jms-ra.rar 
14:08:05,740 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view META-INF/ra.xml in .../deploy/mail-ra.rar 
14:08:07,019 INFO  [WrapperDataSourceService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=DefaultDS' to JNDI name 'java:DefaultDS' 
14:08:07,315 INFO  [A] Bound to JNDI name: queue/A 
14:08:07,315 INFO  [B] Bound to JNDI name: queue/B 
14:08:07,331 INFO  [C] Bound to JNDI name: queue/C 
14:08:07,331 INFO  [D] Bound to JNDI name: queue/D 
14:08:07,331 INFO  [ex] Bound to JNDI name: queue/ex 
14:08:07,347 INFO  [testTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/testTopic 
14:08:07,347 INFO  [securedTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/securedTopic 
14:08:07,362 INFO  [testDurableTopic] Bound to JNDI name: topic/testDurableTopic  
14:08:07,362 INFO  [testQueue] Bound to JNDI name: queue/testQueue 
14:08:07,425 INFO  [UILServerILService] JBossMQ UIL service available at : /0.0.0.0:8093 
14:08:07,487 INFO  [DLQ] Bound to JNDI name: queue/DLQ 
14:08:07,659 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=ConnectionFactoryBinding,name=JmsXA' to JNDI name 'java:JmsXA'
14:09:27,726 INFO  [TomcatDeployer] deploy, ctxPath=/axis2, warUrl=.../tmp/deploy/tmp3181axis2-exp.war/ 
14:09:28,116 INFO  [WebappClassLoader] validateJarFile(C:\Program Files\jboss\jboss-4.0.5.GA\server\default\.\tmp\deploy\tmp3181axis2-exp.war\WEB-INF\lib\servle t-api-2.3.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class 
14:09:29,957 INFO  [ModuleDeployer] Deploying module: addressing-1.4 - file:/C:/Program Files/jboss/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/default/./tmp/deploy/tmp3181axis2-exp. war/WEB-INF/modules/addressing-1.4.mar 
14:09:30,035 INFO  [ModuleDeployer] Deploying module: script-1.4 - file:/C:/Program Files/jboss/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/default/./tmp/deploy/tmp3181axis2-exp.war/ WEB-INF/modules/axis2-scripting-1.4.mar 
14:09:30,160 INFO  [ModuleDeployer] Deploying module: metadataExchange-1.4 - file:/C:/Program Files/jboss/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/default/./tmp/deploy/tmp3181axis 2-exp.war/WEB-INF/modules/mex-1.4.mar 
14:09:30,222 INFO  [ModuleDeployer] Deploying module: ping-1.4 - file:/C:/Program Files/jboss/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/default/./tmp/deploy/tmp3181axis2-exp.war/WE B-INF/modules/ping-1.4.mar 
14:09:30,300 INFO  [ModuleDeployer] Deploying module: soapmonitor-1.4 - file:/C:/Program Files/jboss/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/default/./tmp/deploy/tmp3181axis2-exp .war/WEB-INF/modules/soapmonitor-1.4.mar 
14:09:30,316 INFO  [RepositoryListener] java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 16: file:/C:/Program Files/jboss/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/d efault/tmp/deploy/tmp3158mex-1.4-impl.jar 
14:09:30,409 INFO  [ModuleDeployer] Deploying module: metadataExchange - file:/C:/Program Files/jboss/jboss-4.0.5.GA/server/default/./tmp/deploy/tmp3181axis2-ex p.war/WEB-INF/lib/mex-1.4-impl.jar 
14:09:30,877 WARN  [Utils] Exception extracting jars into temporary directory: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\jboss\jboss-4.0.5.GA\server\defa ult\.\tmp\deploy\tmp3181axis2-exp.war\WEB-INF (Access is denied) : switching to alternate class loading mechanism 
14:09:30,877 INFO  [JAXWSDeployer] Deploying Exception Occured with java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\jboss\jboss-4.0.5.GA\server\default\.\tmp\de ploy\tmp3181axis2-exp.war\WEB-INF (Access is denied) java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\jboss\jboss-4.0.5.GA\server\default\.\tmp\deploy\tmp3181axis2-exp.war\WEB-INF (Access is denied)
         at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.findLibJars(Utils.java:869)
         at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.createClassLoader(Utils.java:917)
         at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSDeployer.deployServicesInWARClassPath(JAXWSDeployer.java:100)
         at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSDeployer.init(JAXWSDeployer.java:80)
         at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.initializeDeployers(DeploymentEngine.java:928)
         at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.setConfigContext(DeploymentEngine.java:919)
         at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.setConfigContext(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:350)
         at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:76)
         at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:511)
         at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:431)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1105)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:932)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3951)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4225)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:759)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:739)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:524) 
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
         at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:503)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5052)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
         at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:503)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
         at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatD eployer.java:297)
         at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:103)
         at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:371) 
         at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
         at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
         at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
         at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
         at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
         at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
         at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
         at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
         at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
         at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
         at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
         at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
         at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
         at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:46 6)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
         at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
         at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
         at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
         at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
         at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
         at org.jboss.ws.integration.jboss.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:92)
         at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
         at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
         at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
         at $Proxy39.start(Unknown Source)
         at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
         at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
         at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
         at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
         at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
         at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
         at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
         at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
         at $Proxy8.deploy(Unknown Source)
         at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
         at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
         at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
         at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
         at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
         at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
         at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
         at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
         at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
         at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
         at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
         at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
         at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
         at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
         at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
         at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
         at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
         at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
         at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
         at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
         at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
         at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
         at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
         at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
         at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
         at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
         at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
         at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
         at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
         at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:490)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\jboss\jboss-4.0.5.GA\server\default\.\tmp\deploy\tmp3181axis2-exp.war\WEB-INF (Access is denied)
         at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
         at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
         at org.jboss.net.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:105)
         at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1009)
         at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.findLibJars(Utils.java:851)
         ... 146 more
```

Answer (score 4):

maybe you should look at this, your servlet seems wrong.

> [WebappClassLoader] validateJarFile(C:\Program Files\jboss\jb oss-4.0.5.GA\server\default.\tmp\deploy\tmp3181axis2-exp.war\WEB-INF\lib\servle t-api-2.3.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2.

Comment: or any *"Problem starting service...", "Fatal error, failed to load application configuration file..."*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can try:

1. Stop the JBoss server, delete tmp and work folders under / and then restart the server
2. This might not be the reason for your issue, but try to avoid running Java application from a path that has a whitespace in it.  It seems your JBoss is deployed under **Program Files** folder.  You may want to move it to somewhere else.

Comment: hi..helios thanks for your reply.. but it doesnt work yet.. :(

Comment: Have you moved your JBoss to different folder "without" any spaces and tried?

Comment: you're getting same exceptions: URISyntaxException and FileNotFoundException (Access Denied)?